# Make Table Query and Delete Query Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm working from Excel and automatically opening up Access and running a macro that will import data, refresh my queries, and export them.

However, two of my queries are more difficult. I have a make table query that runs from a Find Duplicates query and then a delete query that takes out the duplicates from the same table. I am assuming that if I want the table to update I have to re-run the make table and delete queries with my newly imported data. How can I do this in Access?

I have tried looking it up and it appears that maybe the runSQL command is what I should use? I'm not sure how to format it though, especially because when I try to include my SQL version of my queries, VBA doesn't accept it.

Also, should I do this as a separate macro? Or can I run it within the one that I am working in?

Here is the SQL from the two queries:

For the make table query:

```
SELECT [NameDupQuery1].* INTO [TableMakingAndEditing]
FROM [NameDupQuery1];
```

For the delete query:

```
DELETE [TableMakingAndEditing].Carrier, [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field1], [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field2], [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field3], [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field4], [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field5], [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field6], [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field7], [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field8]
FROM [TableMakingAndEditing]
WHERE ((([TableMakingAndEditing].Carrier) In (SELECT [Carrier] FROM [TableMakingAndEditing] As Tmp GROUP BY [Carrier],[Field1],[Field2] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [Field1] = [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field1] And [Field2] = [TableMakingAndEditing].[Field2])));
```

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind! I found out that as long as I already have the queries made, just using

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("MakeTable Query")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Delete from table query")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Will run my make table query and the delete query! Awesome!